# Skiping callbacks during my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, integration-testing

I have the following callback 
`before_action :forbid_logged_user, only: [:new, :create]` that basically prevent a user to access (new) the login page and submit (create) log in credentials when he's already logged in.

```
def forbid_logged_user
  if logged_in?
    flash[:danger] = "You're already logged in"
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

However, I have an integration test that execute a post request (create) to simulate a log in.

```
test "login without remembering" do
  log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
  log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
  assert_empty cookies['remember_token']
end
```

As you can imagine, the post request is ignored because of the call back, therefore returning false in the test. Indeed, the test works well when the I remove the `before_action` callback for the `create` action, but I don't want to.

How can I skip the callback only during tests?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can check environment to skip callback in test environment, for example:

```
if !Rails.env.test? && logged_in?
  flash[:danger] = "You're already logged in"
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

Comment: But I have to do that for every single test involving callbacks. Isn't there a more practical way to do it?

Comment: so you need to define in your test another controller which inherits your controller which has callbacks, and add `skip_before_action` for that controller. Then you need to make all requests in your test go to that controller instead of original controller.